# How do call an Jquery Ajax function on Jquery UI Dialog button call

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery

I just want to call a jQuery Ajax "POST" request on Jquery UI dialog's button call, here is the code snippet,

```
    $("#addqust").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 630,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        position: { my: "top", at: "top", of: window },
        buttons: {
            "Save": function (e) {                        
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/InsertQuestion",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                                                        
                    data: { name: $("#qst").val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log($("#qst").val());
                        console.log(data.d);
                        // alert("message");
                    }
                    }).done(function (msg) {
                        alert("Data Saved ");
                });
            },
            "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
```

but I'm getting the following error or console.log, and not calling the Page Web method,

```
POST http://localhost:50583/Default.aspx/InsertQuestion 500 (Internal Server Error) 
send 
v.extend.ajax 
$.dialog.buttons.Save 
(anonymous function) 
v.event.dispatch 
o.handle.u
```

I would like to know what error I made, appreciate your help.

Update the WebMethod, its a simple method for testing,

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string InsertQuestion(string name)
{
    try
    {           
        string strjson;
        strjson = name;
        return strjson;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new System.Exception( ex.Message);
    }
}
```

jquery versions used,

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: `Default.aspx/InsertQuestion` doesn't look valid. Do you have a web service or web api controller you're trying to call?

Comment: I have included the "[WebMethod()]" before page method

Comment: @JasonP - He is using an ASP.NET AJAX Page Method, which uses the `WebMethod` attribute. It essentially creates a stand-alone web service method inside your `.aspx` page.

Comment: Please show the code for your `InsertQuestion` method in your code-behind.

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case, `500` usually means there's an error on the server side. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: its simple function just return the same string which pass as parameter, just for testing now

Comment: @Karl updated the WebMethod function

Comment: @Delphian - If you put a break point on the following line: `string strjson;`, does it hit the break point? If so, what is the value of `name`?

Comment: yes, the ajax call not coming there :(

Comment: @Delphian - What browser are you using?

Comment: Bring up `Chrome Developer Tools` and see what is reported in the console when you run the application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33153/discussion-between-karl-and-delphian)

Answer (score 0):

Install Fiddler and take a look at the traffic.  Your post has an error, or at least the server is returning 500.

http://fiddler2.com/

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your data object is not a JSON string. Try this in your ajax call:

```
buttons: {
        "Save": function (e) {  
            var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ name: $("#qst").val() });                      

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Default.aspx/InsertQuestion",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                                                        
                data: dataToSend,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log($("#qst").val());
                    console.log(data.d);
                    // alert("message");
                }
                }).done(function (msg) {
                    alert("Data Saved ");
            });
        },
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
```

Include [JSON.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) for older browsers.