# Passing value of an onclick event to the controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a button that triggers a "delete" event. This event updates a db entry through a stored proc in case the user decides to continue. However, users can only mark a location as closed (they cannot revert back to open). The default value of a location is declared as string status="1" for open (and as a varchar(1) equaling '1' in the stored proc). If the status is "0" it means the location is closed.

My question is...how can I make it so that the event reflects the change in my controller that handles the update? Does it matter that the variable is declared as a string?

button:

```
<button type="submit" name="RemoveAccount" id="RemoveAccount" onclick="Confirm_delete()" value="@Model.Location.status">Remove</button>
```

JS:

```
 function Confirm_delete()
{
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this entry?');
};
```

Comment: you can use jquery dialog and call your controller using ajax check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17554389/how-do-call-an-jquery-ajax-function-on-jquery-ui-dialog-button-call

Comment: What exactly are you asking? To change `Confirm_delete` so that it takes the `value` of the button into account?

Comment: Yea, I want the value to change to "0" if the user proceeds with the delete. If they don't, then leave as the default "1".

Comment: You need `onclick="return Confirm_delete()"` for the return from the function to take effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `if` to your function:

```
function Confirm_delete(el) {
    if (el.value === '1') {
        el.value = '0';
        return confirm('Are you sure you want to remove this entry?');
    }
    return false;
}
```

As @Alex mentioned in the comments, do change the `onclick` to `return Confirm_delete(this)`. Note I also added `this` as an argument to be clear we want to get a reference to the button.

Note that since the button you have has `type="submit"` the button should submit the form, which will cause the server to get involved. If you've mapped your model correctly, the value of `@Model.Location.status` should change to "0" by the time the page rerenders.